# Windows Forms Saving controls Layout Information using XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I have designed a form to create controls like textbox, panels buttons dynamically. I have an option to edit the size and position of the controls. I need to maintain the layout and the parent and child relation of the controls so that I can save the information and re-create it when loaded again. Is there any other better option other than XML to maintain the layout information?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `app.config` file it'll provide you better operations and will save a lot of code that you'll be doing right now to iterate through your saved XML file.
For more info [Go here](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/01/04/64871.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option of saving it in the **database** (per user if required)?  If you have to implement it file-based XML is probably the easiest option, whether you go the app.config route or write your own class to save and retrieve custom user settings from XML - a good place to save this might be the user's **AppData** folder.

Anything saved to app.config might be lost when you use something like **ClickOnce** to do version upgrades.